# Facebook default landing tab for fans

Tags: facebook

I am having trouble setting up default landing tab for fans. Apparently the Landing Tab featured in Manage Permissions works only for Non-Fans. So when a fan returns to the page is currently being redirected to Wall rather than the Default Landing Tab. How do I make a fan redirect to a custom default landing tab apart from the Wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for this and this is standard behavior for a long time.  You can only set a landing page for non-fans. You can log a feature request [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).